# Pegar linha Selecionada no DataGrid Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Xamarin-Forms utilizando o padrão MVVM e estou com a seguinte dificuldade. Em uma das minhas telas estou utilizando um DataGrid para exibir algumas informações separadas por linhas e colunas, quando o usuário clicar em uma das linhas preciso disparar um evento utilizando um Binding, porém estou com essa dificuldade. Gostaria de saber como deve ser construído esse método que recebe o evento do ItemSelected do DataGrid, utilizando o modelo MVVM. Tentei utilizar um método {get; set;} que recebe um objeto da minha classe que preenche o DataGrid, porém não funcionou.

Código da Minha View:

```
namespace AprovacaoMetagal.ViewModel
{
    public class DetAprovViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public Aprovacao aprovacao { get; set; }
        private Aprovacao aprovacaoSelect;

        public Aprovacao AprovacaoSelecionadaDet
        {
            get
            {
                return aprovacaoSelect;
            }
            set
            {
                aprovacaoSelect = value;

                if (aprovacaoSelect != null)
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send(aprovacaoSelect, "AprovacaoSelecionadaDetalheDet");
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem> listaDetalhes { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem> ListaDetalhes
        {
            get
            {
                return listaDetalhes;
            }
            set
            {
                this.listaDetalhes = value;
            }
        }

        public DetAprovViewModel(Aprovacao aprovacao)
        {
            this.aprovacao = aprovacao;
            this.listaDetalhes = new ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem>();

            AprovacaoCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<Aprovacao>(aprovacao, "AprovacaoSelecionadaDetalheDet");
            });

            CarregarListaDetalhes();
        }

        public void CarregarListaDetalhes()
        {
            this.ListaDetalhes.Clear();

            if(this.aprovacao.TipoDocumento==1)
            {
                 this.ListaDetalhes = new ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem>
                 {
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 195053,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,02).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Gerente"},
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 195552,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,10).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Diretor"},
                 };
            }
            else if(this.aprovacao.TipoDocumento==5)
            {
                this.ListaDetalhes = new ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem>
                 {
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 196053,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,02).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Gerente"},
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 196552,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,10).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Conselho"},
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 196852,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,10).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Diretor"},
                 };
            }
            else
            {
                this.ListaDetalhes = new ObservableCollection<AprovacaoListagem>
                 {
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 195553,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,02).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Gerente"},
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 196552,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,10).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Custos"},
                    new AprovacaoListagem { Aprovacao = 196852,Data = new DateTime(2018,03,10).ToShortDateString(),Perfil="Diretor"},
                 };
            }
        }

        public ICommand AprovacaoCommand { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Teria como colocar o seu código? Assim ficará mais fácil para a comunidade lhe ajudar.

Comment: DataGrid? É algum componente externo ao XF?